# Программа рекурсии находит N-е число Фибоначчи с течением времени T. За какое время эта программа найдет N + 1 число, N + 2, 2N?

Tags: python

Есть программа нахождения n-нного числа Фибоначчи:

```
def fibonacci(a):
    if a != 0 and a != 1:
        return fibonacci(a - 1) + fibonacci(a - 2)
    else:
        return a


n = int(input())
print(fibonacci(n))
```

Найти время для  N + 1, N + 2, 2N

Comment: Подсказка - нужно посчитать количество вызовов рекурсивной функции для аргумента n

Answer (score 1):

[Формула числа вызовов рекурсивной функции для расчёта чисел Фибоначчи](https://vulms.vu.edu.pk/Courses/CS201/Downloads/p60-robertson.pdf):

```
G(N) = 2*F(N) - 1
```

Где:

- `G(N)` - число вызовов функции при расчёте N-го числа Фибоначчи
- `F(N)` - N-е число Фибоначчи.

Answer (score 0):

Дам вырезку [отсюда](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/449616/)

Выражаясь грубым языком O-нотации, такое решение имеет временную сложность O(e^n). То есть — время выполнения этой функции растёт экспоненциально при увеличении n. То есть — когда n увеличивается на, время выполнения увеличивается в. Грубо говоря, если fib(45) вам пришлось ждать час, то fib(46) вы будете ждать два часа, fib(47) — 4 часа, и так далее. Я разжёвываю так подробно, чтобы каждый читатель, даже верстальщик, впервые попробовавший свои силы в написании скриптов, мог осознать ужас ситуации.

Можно получить более точную оценку числа вызов функции ~(1+sqrt(5)) fib(n)